# Filling a struct based on substring matches within a loop

Tags: string, go, struct, slice

If we take a look at the following code, how can we fill a struct variable with values taken from a slice of strings? https://go.dev/play/p/KkcPzr5r28w

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type Config struct {
    Operation string
    Stop      string
    Start     string
    File      string
}

func ParseConfig(list []string) Config {

    var c Config
    for _, elem := range list {
        if strings.Contains(elem, "op:") {
            subList := strings.SplitAfterN(elem, ":", 2)
            c.Operation = subList[1]
        } else if strings.Contains(elem, "stop:") {
            subList := strings.SplitAfterN(elem, ":", 2)
            c.Stop = subList[1]
        } else if strings.Contains(elem, "start:") {
            subList := strings.SplitAfterN(elem, ":", 2)
            c.Start = subList[1]
        } else if strings.Contains(elem, "file:") {
            subList := strings.SplitAfterN(elem, ":", 2)
            c.File = subList[1]
        }
    }
    return c
}

func main() {

    c := ParseConfig(os.Args[1:])
    fmt.Println(c) // {count the  quick /tmp/file1.txt}
}
```

This program doesn't return the right response when invoked with these parameters:

```
go run scan.go op:count start:quick stop:the file:/tmp/file1.txt
```

I was wondering what's wrong? What is the best way to refactor the code to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I've fixed it, thanks to Gophers's community: https://go.dev/play/p/u_Dc7ctbsib

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type Config struct {
    Operation string
    Stop      string
    Start     string
    File      string
}

func main() {
    list := []string{"op:count", "start:quick", "stop:the", "file:/tmp/file1.txt"}
    fmt.Println(list)
    var c Config
    for _, v := range list {
        if strings.HasPrefix(v, "op:") {
            subList := strings.SplitAfterN(v, ":", 2)
            c.Operation = subList[1]
        } else if strings.Contains(v, "stop:") {
            subList := strings.SplitAfterN(v, ":", 2)
            c.Stop = subList[1]
        } else if strings.Contains(v, "start:") {
            subList := strings.SplitAfterN(v, ":", 2)
            c.Start = subList[1]
        } else if strings.Contains(v, "file:") {
            subList := strings.SplitAfterN(v, ":", 2)
            c.File = subList[1]
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(c) // {count the  quick /tmp/file1.txt}

}
```

[Due to the fact that "stop:the" also wrongly matches "op:"](https://go.dev/play/p/nXinYLc94zT), `Operation` is finally set to "the" instead of "count". The problem seems to be solved now that `strings.Contains` was replaced with `strings.HasPrefix`.